# Possible to use aws s3 sync command to download s3 to local, while ensuring s3 content is untouched?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am trying to download the content of a HUUUGE (20+GB) s3 bucket to my local drive

Problem: I have a flaky network up-and-down can't complete this command:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://sharedfolder/subfolder subfolder
```

I am thinking to try the sync command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://sharedfolder/subfolder subfolder
```

However:
I am a little nervous about running the command because
i don't want partial results in my local folder
to OVERWRITE those in s3.  I want the s3 folder to be untouched, and
only my local updated with content of s3.

Ideally, I'd like some kind of sync mode where I can provide an option similar to

```
git merge -X theirs
```

which merges with precedence given to the content i am merging FROM.

Any AWS/S3 experts who can advise me on this ?

Comment: There's no reason your sync command won't do exactly what you want, it doesn't modify the bucket when using the bucket as the source.  That said, if you have large files you can't download at once, you'll need some other solution, since when you restart a sync after a failure, it won't resume any partially complete files.

Comment: Also note that unless you indicate `--delete` the `aws s3 sync` command will only add/update files in the target; it won't delete files. Bear that in mind if you want the target to be a replica of the source.

Comment: thanks @AnonCoward et. al. - I am trying cyberduck -